# Get Email address from iPhone Address Book

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am currently able to successfully access and get data from the `peoplePickerNavigationController`, but what I would like to do is have the email address of the contact be accessed, then the modal window dismissed when the contact name is pressed.

Scenario:

```
"Button is clicked to add a contact
AddressBook Modal Window slides into view
Name of Contact is pressed
If available, the contact's email address is stored in an array
Dismiss modal window"
```

My current code consists of:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    ABMultiValueRef container = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFStringRef contactData = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(container, identifier);
    CFRelease(container);
    NSString *contactString = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)contactData];
    CFRelease(contactData);

    NSLog(@"Value is: %@", contactString);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what i do.

```
if(property == kABPersonEmailProperty) {
  CFTypeRef prop = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
  CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(prop,  identifierForValue);
  NSString *email = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(prop, index);

  ...

  CFRelease(prop);
  [email release];
}
```

Comment: now do I put this in the `peoplePickerNavigationController: shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: property: identifier:` method? Because this is doing the same thing the code I supplied does...

Comment: sorry, yes that needs to be in the method, then if you opened the PeoplePicker modally you need to dismiss it as you have above.