# Fetch all email-id of contact list of iphone in to the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to fetch all email id's of contacts which is present in contact list of iPhone. and then all  email id to show in picker View in app. please  give me ideas to solve this problem.
Thanks to all,

Comment: What did you try? Goggled anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875135/get-email-address-from-iphone-address-book refer this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out,

```
    ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray* allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);

   NSMutableDictionary  *contactsInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[allPeople count]];

    for (id record in allPeople) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *propertyList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        CFTypeRef emailProp = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        NSString *email = [((NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProp)) objectAtIndex:0 ];
        if (!email) {
            email = @"";  
        }

        [propertyList setObject:email forKey:@"Email"];

        [contactsInformation setObject:propertyList forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID((ABRecordRef)record)]];

        [propertyList release];
    }
    CFRelease(_addressBookRef);
    [allPeople release];
    allPeople = nil;
```